# unable to url from this string using xpath?

Tags: html, xhtml, xpath, html-parsing

I want to get the url of the Download hyper link from this link: http://mp3skull.com/mp3/aadat.html 
This is the string that I have written: //div[1]/[text() = 'Download'] (and this is only for the first object you ll see what I mean). What am I doing wrong here? If possible could you give me the correct string?

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following xpath retrieve the first download link:

`/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a`

Not very smart, I would try to get all download links with something like:

`//div/div[2]/a`

Comment: welcome, I've tried to answer the other question you have. Mark it as answer or vote up if it's helpful.

Comment: Hi, what if I want to get title of the second song?

Comment: `/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/b`